# Qualified type displayed in combobox instead of property value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a problem with my combobox.
I've set DataSource which contains a list of objects, DisplayMember and also ValueMember but there are times when the combobox displays the namespace where the object class is placed. For example: **Project.Interface.Object**

```
cmbAuto.DataSource = Collections.ProfileList.FindAll(t => t.IsAuto);
cmbAuto.DisplayMember = "Name";
cmbAuto.ValueMember = "ID";
cmbAuto.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: Here is the code:                                                                                                                                        cmbAuto.DataSource = Collections.ProfileList.FindAll(t => t.IsAuto);
            cmbAuto.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cmbAuto.ValueMember = "ID";
            cmbAuto.SelectedIndex = -1;

Answer (score 0):

I suggets you to use `Where operator`

```
cmbAuto.DataSource = Collections.ProfileList.Where(t => t.IsAuto);
```

Nota : FindAll() is a function on the List type, it's not a LINQ extension method like Where.

Comment: Unfortunately the Where clause does not work.That Project.Interface.Object appears again. Other suggestions?

Comment: in this case you cast on your type with ProfileList.Cast<YourType>.Where(t => t.IsAuto)

Comment: I've solved the problem by overriding ToString method of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by overriding ToString method of the object.